# Why does my custom CSS tag place quotes when I apply it to some text

Tags: html, css

Ok so I am very new to CSS and HTML. Basically I have the below code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
p
{
    font-family:Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

q
{
    color:#698B22;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>
Foo Bar Foo bar.
<br /><br />
Foo <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">Bar</a> Foo Bar.
<br /><br />
Foo <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">Bar <q>Foo</q> Bar</a> Foo Bar.
<br /><br />
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I view this in my Browser, it looks like so:

[image: HTML Rendered by browser]

What I want to know is, why, on the third line, is there quotes around the word `Foo` inside the link (in the most recent versions of Chrome and Firefox, this is not present in IE9)? Also, how do I get shot of the quotes?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`q` is not a custom tag, it [already exists](http://www.quackit.com/html/tags/html_q_tag.cfm).

Answer (score 1):

works in IE9 so I would probably guess you are not declaring a doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1):

The  tags are telling the browser to put quotes around the word Foo

Answer (score 0):

You have added the HTML short quote tag to your link.  Remove the q part and the quotes will go away.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_q.asp

If you wanted to do what you're doing in CSS:
    `Foo <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">Bar <span class="q">Foo</span> Bar</a> Foo Bar.`

and change your CSS to:
    `.q 
    { 
        color:#698B22; 
    }`

Note that you can't create new HTML elements in CSS - you can override the deafult settings or create new classes or IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Since `<q>` Tag mean *quote*, some browsers will automatically add *quotation marks* around the content.
In this particular case, I suggest you use another tag, like: `<em>` instead.
**More**: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/q

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have default style sheets, the one you are using probably adds them, you can override it though,

```
q {
   quotes: none;
}
q:before, q:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<span>Foo</span>` around a word to give it specific CSS styles.